# How to find fields with characters outside of A-Z0-9

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find the fields that have data outside of the normal A-Z, a-z, 0-9 range.
The fields have data in them like: Café or Crème.

This is not working:

```
select FieldData
from Field
WHERE FieldData not like '%[0-9A-Za-z]%'
group by FieldData
```

Answer (score 2):

The `LIKE` operator with a range wildcard is [collation sensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx). The key statement here is:

> In range searches, the characters included in the range may vary
>   depending on the sorting rules of the collation.

Basically, the characters included in the range may not be in line with your expectations when the range is expanded. If you find a collation where all letters a-z/A-Z precede their accented counterparts then things should work. A [binary sort collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143350%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) collation should do this, which:

> sort data based on the sequence of coded values defined by the locale
>   and data type.

With `Latin1_General_BIN2` (`_BIN2` is SQL Server 2005+, `_BIN` should work also), the following succeeds:

```
select FieldData
from (select 'abcd' as FieldData union 
      select '1234' union 
      select 'Café' union 
      select 'Crème') as Field
WHERE FieldData COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 like '%[^0-9A-Za-z]%'

--output:
--Café
--Crème
```

Notice, you have to invert the `not like` to a `like` and change the pattern to a "not" range (`[^]`) as your original query will still exclude Café and Crème as they have non-accented characters.